# Alignment issue with the textAngular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

Getting empty p tags like this

how to restrict this tags.with this User Interface is affecting.Attaching the screen.[image]

and concern issue link https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/598